# How to release a resource from class.getResource()

Tags: java, testing, gradle, groovy, resources

In a test I am trying to test for the correct behaviour when a configuration file is absent.

```
    given:
    File settingsGradleFile = new File( 'src/main/resources/settings.gradle')
    settingsGradleFile.renameTo 'src/main/resources/settings.gradle_OLD'

    ...

    when: 
    App.instance.start(mockStage)

    // now rename it back to its original name
    // NB in practice I put renameTo() in the "cleanup" block - but I have tested in both
    boolean result = settingsGradleFile.renameTo 'src/main/resources/settings.gradle'
    log.debug("result of rename: $result")
```

The first `renameTo` works fine. The second returns `false` (and the file name stays at "settings.gradle_OLD").  In the code of the CUT we have:

```
        URL settingsGradleURL = App.class.getResource( '/settings.gradle' )
        ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse( settingsGradleURL )
        projectName = conf.rootProject.name
```

I may be wrong, but it seems that the second `renameTo` is failing because in the mean time this `getResource()` operation has happened. How can I get this resource to be "released"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second fails because `settingsGradleFile` still refers to the original name `"settings.gradle"`, not the new name `"settings.gradle_OLD"`.

Calling `renameTo` does not update the `File` object, since `File` objects are immutable.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm sure that would have taken me hours to work out!